how to push data from sagemaker to open search in aws?
I am new to opensearch service, based on the documentation, it looks like I can make a post request (sample below) to post some data to open search database. I want to generate embeddings using openAI api , or for testing within aws sagemaker. is http post only way to upload data into open ai . if I have several thousand documents and say I generate the embedding for each document and store it somewhere in s3 bucket. how can I upload the data into my open search database. is there a batch processing support for such , or do I have to upload the embeddings one by one?
POST _bulk
{ "create": { "_index": "students", "_id": "2" } }
{ "name": "Jonathan Powers", "gpa": 3.85, "grad_year": 2025 }
{ "create": { "_index": "students", "_id": "3" } }
{ "name": "Jane Doe", "gpa": 3.52, "grad_year": 2024 }

